# File writing Java EE Web App with use of Jboss modules

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-modules

I would like to save files in a Java EE web application deployed to a JBoss (EAP 6.1+).
Using a database is not an option.
I have read all answers which sound similar to this topic (especially from BalusC).
However, I am not quite sure if my thoughts on this are completely clear.

My current implementation has till now been tested only on a local jboss server. I have made **use of JBoss modules** to save my resources and more specifically:

1. I have created a new jboss module
2. and I am accessing my resources (from the Servlet container and not from        an EJB container) path via:
       getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/my_path")

Given that I am **not writing any files** **to** (or reading from) **the deployment folder**,
I am not expecting any problems to occur after restarting jboss (eg loss of data).

In a stage where multitple machines are used (for *load balancing*) is it expected that the files are only visible to the machine where a file is written? Or are the contents of jboss **modules at all machines visible and synchronized?**

If one takes also into account that no parallel attempts will be made to access some resource simultaneously:
    Are there any other circumstances where inconistencies/problem should be expected?